# Local Image Paths in PhoneGap www don't work on iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, cordova, path, webkit

This works in iOS 6 and not iOS 5, so I'm assuming it's a webkit thing.

I have an image in my `www/images` folder, so I use the following html:

```
<img src="images/img.gif" />
```

However the image appears as the blue square with a question mark (iOS's *image not found* image).

**How can I get this path to work on both iOS 5 and iOS 6?**

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the HTML file, from which you are calling this path, is on the same directory level as your images folder ?

Comment: It isn't. I'm calling that image from a file loaded by `RequireJS` at `1/2/3/4/5/x.html`, but relative paths are not working here either (ie. `../../../../images/img.gif`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the same problem, the same code works fine in a local browser and in iOS6 onwards but doesn't display an image in iOS4.3, 5.0 or 5.1.

The solution that worked for me was to use a background image instead and style it with CSS, it also means that you can provide a high-res retina image and scale it for non-retina devices too.

replace your IMG tag with:

```
<div id="myImage" />
```

In your CSS file :

```
#myImage
{
    background-image:url("../../assets/images/img.gif"); // The relative path from your CSS file to your image
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100px;  // Actual image size is 200px x 200px
    height:100px;
}
```

The relative path to images from within a CSS file appears to work ok, but the path must be relative to the css file and not your html file.

If you want an image to display a 100px by 100px image on a non-retina device, you should create an image that is twice the size (200px x 200px) and let background:cover automatically change to the higher resolution when your app is running on a retina device.